# Joomla save method override

Tags: methods, joomla, save, overriding

I have a xml form with some text fields, checkboxes, ... How can I get the entered values of the form in an override save method in my controller file? (Joomla 3.x)

```
function save($data) {
    print_r($data); // <-- this shows nothing!
                    // or
    print_r(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform')); // <-- this shows "Array"
                    // or 
    print_r(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform')['NameOfaField']); // <-- this shows "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' "

    // parent::save($data);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print_r(JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('jform', array(), 'ARRAY'));
```

That should return the actual array of values. The extra two options set a default and set the type of filtering to use. Joomla's default filtering does not allow an array of values, so you need to specifically request it.

Comment: If you want the validated data you can use the postsave hook.